# Importing variable to vue file from remotely hosted file

Tags: vue.js, import, vuejs2

I want to import a variable to vue component from a remotely hosted file that I cannot change.

```
//www.example.com/remote_file.js
var remoteVariable = '12345';
```

```
// Home.vue
//What should I do here,
```

if I can edit the remote file like `export var remoteVariable = '12345'` that, I know I should be able to import it like this,

```
//Home.vue
<script>
  import { remoteVariable } from 'www.example.com/remote_file.js'`
...
</script>
```

But In my case, I cannot change the remote file. Can anybody help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What if you load the remote script before your Home.vue script, something like this:

```
<script src="https://www.example.com/remote_file.js"></script>
<!-- then your home.vue -->
<script>
  // ...
  console.log(remoteVariable);
  // ...
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is possible I guess, But it's an ugly way of doing it, 
1) vue won't allow me to use another script tag inside the .vue Component.
2) even if I imported file in somewhere else in the project, I may run into all kinds of eslint errors. =D I am looking for a much more cleaner way of doing this.